# when i resize browser window content in div comes out from div it should not come out from

Tags: html, css

[image]When i resize the browser window content in div comes out of the div. It should  stay in its position  when i zoom out and zoom in browser window irrespective of width and height of and browser window and content div must adjust automatically with dynamic height and width of browser:

```css
.item: {
  display: table;
  word-break: break-all;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: silver;
  border-radius: 4px;
  );
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
}

.awesome {
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .12);
  margin: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  display: table-cell;
  font-size: 1em;
}

.fa-bars: {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 16px;
  font-size: 5em;
  color: coral;
  display: table-cell
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"></link>
</head>

<body>
  <div >
    <ul>
      <li gridster-item="item" ng-repeat="item in Items">
        <div class="awesome">hello world
          <i class="fa fa-bars"></i></div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The HTML does not match the CSS: the selector `.gridster` in the CSS would match an element with class "gridster", not an element with an attribute called `gridster`. Unless you're leaving out some vital information! Also, you shouldn't have a block element directly in a table element without table rows and cells in between; not all browsers may handle this the same way. And you have a missing selicolon in the CSS. And the `top` property doesn't do anything in a non-positioned element.

Comment: okay Thanks @ Mr Lister

Comment: how can i solve it

Comment: First of all, create a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue. The source in your question currently does not show the ul coming out of the div when the window is resized. Also, fix the errors. And tell us what libraries you're using; I can find multiple things on the net called "gridster", so it would be nice to mention which one you mean.

Comment: thanks @mr lister what i need is content in div comes out from div when i resize browser

Comment: what is the use of gridster here? is it a class name? or the Angular-Gridster/Gridster.js ?

Comment: its an angular gridster. for just an example purpose  i had mention it i hope u had understand my question

Answer (score 0):

```css
.item {
  display: table;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  word-break: break-all;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: silver;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
@-ms-viewport{
  width: device-width;
}
.awesome {
  padding: 10px 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  background: none;
  text-align: center;
  color: #30a5ff;
  top: 105px;
  text-align: center font-size: 1em;
}


/*
.fa-check-square:before {
  top: 15px;
  right: 16px;
  font-size: 5em;
  color: coral;
  display: table-cell
} */
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-+d0P83n9kaQMCwj8F4RJB66tzIwOKmrdb46+porD/OvrJ+37WqIM7UoBtwHO6Nlg" crossorigin="anonymous">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="viewport" content="height=device-height, initial-scale=1">
<div gridster="gridsterOpts" align="center">
  <ul>
    <li gridster-item="item" ng-repeat="item in Items" class="item" align="center">
      <h2 class="awesome" align="right">Hello world! <i class="fa fa-check-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></h2>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

HTML Code: (together)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-+d0P83n9kaQMCwj8F4RJB66tzIwOKmrdb46+porD/OvrJ+37WqIM7UoBtwHO6Nlg" crossorigin="anonymous">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="viewport" content="height=device-height, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.item {
  display: table;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  word-break: break-all;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: silver;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
@-ms-viewport {
 width: device-width;
}
.awesome {
  padding: 10px 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  background: none;
  text-align: center;
  color: #30a5ff;
  top: 105px;
  text-align: center font-size: 1em;
}


/*
.fa-check-square:before {
  top: 15px;
  right: 16px;
  font-size: 5em;
  color: coral;
  display: table-cell
} */
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div gridster="gridsterOpts" align="center">
  <ul>
    <li gridster-item="item" ng-repeat="item in Items" class="item" align="center">
      <h2 class="awesome" align="right">Hello world! <i class="fa fa-check-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></h2>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169323/discussion-between-pradeep-and-ag-boss).